# Aptitude simplification question

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Given $$p+q+r=1\;\;\;\;\&\;\;\;p^2+q^2+r^2=2\;\;\;\;\&\;\;\;p^3+q^3+r^3=3$$

find the value of  $$p^4+q^4+r^4$$

Comment: Hello and welcome to the community!  Here is a quick guide on how to format your math: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Aptitude simplification?

Answer (score 3):

More generally, we have that for all $a,b,c\in\mathbb R$, $n\in\mathbb Z$, $n\ge 0$:

$$S_{n+3}=S_{n+2}S_1-S_{n+1}(ab+bc+ca)+S_{n}(abc),$$

where $S_n=a^n+b^n+c^n$. It can be proved by simply expanding.

Also notice $ab+bc+ca=\frac{(a+b+c)^2-\left(a^2+b^2+c^2\right)}{2}$.

Now apply this for your problem. Let $(a,b,c)=(p,q,r)$ and also let firstly $n=0$ (to find $pqr$) and then $n=1$ (to find $p^4+q^4+r^4$).

Comment: Thanks bhai,its very helpful and easy

Comment: Answer is 25/6 ok

Comment: @MaheshSharma The proper way to thank someone for an answer is to accept it (the checkmark) and upvote it (the up arrow). You can upvote more than one answer if there are several you like.

Answer (score 0):

By using [Newton's identities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_identities), finally you should find that
$$s_4=\frac{s_1^4+8s_1 s_3-6s_2 s_1^2+3s_2^2}{6}$$
where $s_i=p^k+q^k+r^k$. In your case 
$$p^4+q^4+r^4=s_4=\frac{1+24-12+12}{6}=\frac{25}{6}.$$